# Auto It Combo Box with Control Command selection disappears

Tags: combobox, autoit

I'm working with AutoIt and want to control a combobox with ControlCommand. I'm able to change the value but when I jump to the next command it will be reset.

I tried several ways,

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/109893-combo-box-click-item/

but it's not working.

```
$hComBo=ControlGetHandle("","","[CLASS:TComboBox; INSTANCE:6]")
$aList = _GUICtrlComboBox_GetListArray($hComBo)
;_ArrayDisplay($aList)
Select
Case $Baudrate=5
    ControlCommand($hWnd,"",$hComBo,"SelectString",$aList[7])
    MsgBox($MB_OKCANCEL," Info ", @error & " - Element: " & $aList[7])
    ;_GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel($hComBo,5)
    ;$iCode = $CBN_SELCHANGE
    ;$val = BitShift($iCode, -16)
    ;_SendMessage($hWnd, $WM_COMMAND, $val, $hComBo)
    ;MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL," Info ", "hWnd: "& $hWnd &"- WM-Command: "& $WM_COMMAND &"- val: " & $val  &"- hComBo: " &$hComBo)
    Sleep(3000)
    ;MsgBox($MB_OKCANCEL," Info ", $baudrate)
EndSelect
```

While Sleep(3000) I can see that there is the correct value in the combobox, but after processing the next command it disappears. Any ideas?

Comment: If you change the value manually there is no problem? What is the next step? Maybe the next step in your scripts creates the result.

Comment: The next step is the solution. It´s an TPanel that shows pictures choosen from an TreeView. I changed the order of the commands, (I first choose the first entry now) and it works. Now my settings aren´t overwritten any more.

Comment: I agree with @Xenobiologist. You should post the full script because the snippet you posted surely isn't responsible for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some times it is necessary to send a `WM_COMMAND` -message after seting one entry of list ([source](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/109893-combo-box-click-item/)). But as described in MSDN the `$wParam` to be send has to contain both the `$iCode` AND the `Control-ID`.

To solve this you may use this:

```
$hControl = ControlGetHandle($hExport, "", "[CLASS:ComboBox; INSTANCE:1]") ; get control handle
_GUICtrlComboBox_SetCurSel($hControl, 2) ; select something
$iID = _WinAPI_GetDlgCtrlID($hControl) ; get control ID
$wParam = BitOR($iID, BitShift($CBN_SELCHANGE, -16)) ; put ID and message together

_SendMessage($hExport, $WM_COMMAND, $wParam, $hControl) ; send massage
```